# JS minification issue still pending

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I have tried almost every single thing there were some errors in system.log file i have also removed that , gave so much time to solve this issue . i want to minify and merged js . i set developer mode and select options using store->configuration->advance->developer nothing changed in my site i did run all commands upgrade, content deply , di compile , cache flush everything . gave permissions and all but still no good luck . can anyone give me some good trick ?

Answer (score 0):

Js minification can be done only in production mode. Please change store configurations in developer mode, run all commands and set to production mode to check JS merging and minification.

1.Set Yes for JS merging and minification in `store->configuration->advance->developer` in developer mode

2. cache flush

3.content deploy

4.Set to production mode using command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`
Now JS merging and minification will work

Comment: i have tried it on production mode also .

Comment: currently i am in production mode . but js is not merged .

Comment: i have tried this thing also , i am trying it for 2 days ... tried almost everything ... want to listen something new :)

Comment: Did you enable config merge, min, compile js in develop tab??